# Which is the stable ubuntu 20.04 kernel for laptops?

Tags: sound, 20.04, kernel, brightness, lts

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo AMD powered laptop. But, the brightness slider and sound didn't work. The default kernel was "5.4.0-54-generic" then I updated it to "5.6.0-1034-oem". Both problems have been solved now. Should I continue using this version or move to some another kernel?

Comment: There is no special stable kernel for laptops.  There are 1000s of laptops with need for 1000s of drivers.  Some laptops will need us to add stuff to have all hardware work well, as you found and Pilot6 answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5.4 is the current kernel for Ubuntu 20.04.

The `5.6.0-1034-oem` is a kernel for oem devices. If it works for you, then use it.

Soon there will be the 5.8 HWE kernel that should support AMD GPU's better than the 5.4.

I recommend to install the HWE meta package by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

It won't update anything now, but as soon as the 5.8 HWE is released you'll switch to it automatically on a system update.

Comment: This gives me 5.13 but does not work when selected  on grub. Grub says the boot files cannot be found. What gives?